# Laravel 5 friendly seo urls and urlencode

Tags: laravel, routes, laravel-5.1

In laravel 4.* we had the :any option in routing.
However in laravel 5 we dont have that.. But I need to have a route like http://localhost/laravel/public/Category/%D0%A2%D0%A3%D0%A0%D0%98%D0%97%D0%AA%D0%9C+%D0%A1%D0%9F%D0%9E%D0%A0%D0%A2+2F+%D0%A1%D0%9F%D0%90/3
Where after Category/ I may have any character.

Tried using the reg exp like - Route::get('/Category/{category_name}/{category_id}', 'FrontController@category')->where('category_name','.');
with no success.
How can we deal with that ?

Comment: What do you mean by "no success"? Do you got an error? Isn't it redirected where you want it to be?

Comment: It does not respond to the routing table

Answer (score 0):

With

```
where('category_name','.');
```

you are limiting and forcing the FIRST parameter to be a single character. I guess you meant

```
where('category_id','.');
```

Comment: I need the category_name to respond to any string !

Comment: That's why you don't need to include any constraint for category_name

Comment: Laravel has forbidden chars in the routing! I need to use them such as %

Comment: Sorry, but I replicated your query: http://testpage/Category/%D0%A2%D0%A3%D0%A0%D0%98%D0%97%D0%AA%D0%9C+%D0%A1%D0%9F%D0%9E%D0%A0%D0%A2+2F+%D0%A1%D0%9F%D0%90/3 and the routing worked flawlessly, the URl being automatically translated to http://testpage/Category/ТУРИЗЪМ+СПОРТ+2F+СПА/3